# Xcode 4. Why Can't My Renamed Project Find It's Info.plist File?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, info.plist

Under Xcode 4 I renamed a project from Foo to Bar. The former Foo-Info.plist is renamed as Bar-Info.plist. The renamed file exists. On disk and in the project. All should be cool. All is not cool.

When I compile I get this:

> could not read data from
>   '/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/Users/PATH/TO/Bar-Info.plist':
>   The file “Bar-Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such
>   file.

The file does exist in the path shown as well as in the build settings. Is there some cached data I need to purge to unwedge this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

XCode is looking in the wrong folder for your Info.plist.  Check the Build Setting for Info.plist File; make sure there aren't any qualifiers to the file name.

Comment: How do you "check the build setting"? How do you "make sure there aren't any qualifiers"?

Comment: @Jackie in Xcode 3, the build settings are available through project and Target -> Get Info.  In Xcode 4, select the project in the Command+1 sidebar and check the build settings for the project & the target.

Comment: what are qualifiers? the path to the build settings is correct but it is still throwing that error